# Primefaces dynamic menu icon not showing

Tags: primefaces, icons, menuitem

Im creating my menu intiarly with help of java. Now im trying to set an icon, but it doesn't show.

Here is my css class:

```
    .qualiteatsmanager {
    background: url("/resources/images/icons/qm.png") !important;
    height:16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

Im setting the icon like this: `studentMenuItem.setIcon("qualiteatsmanager");`.

but the menu only shows the standard `ui-icon-carat-1-n`.

[image]

The images can be found under `src/main/java/../resources/images/icons`.

Comment: Have you double checked that the given url is pointing to the right directory?

Comment: yeah im sure. Do i need to put the whole url? from scr/main.. or can i start with subpackages /resources/.. ?

Comment: right now it doesn't show any icon. Not the ui-icon-carat-1-n neither. But i get this error code [http-bio-8080-exec-7][code_jsp:?] {code="404", msg="/resources/images/icons/qm.png", uri=/resources/images/icons/qm.png}